# AJAX long-polling a REST API/Memcached in a PHP application

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, rest, long-polling

No, I'm not trying to see how many buzzwords I can throw into a single question title.

I'm making REST requests through cURL in my PHP app to some webservices. These requests need to be made fairly often since much of the application depends on this API. However, there is severe latency with the requests (2-5 seconds) which just makes my app look painfully slow.

While I'm halfway to a solution with a recommendation to cache these requests in Memcached, I'm still not satisfied with that kind of latency ever appearing within the application.

So here was my thought: I can implement AJAX long-polling in the background so that the user never experiences the latency outright. The REST requests/Memcache lookups will be done all through AJAX at a set interval.

But this is all really new to me and I'm not sure if this is the best approach. And if I'm on the right track, I do know that PHP + Apache is not going to handle something like this well. But PHP is the only language I know. I'd ideally like to set up something like Tornado in Python, but I'm just not sure if I'm over-engineering right now or not.

Any thoughts here would be helpful and much appreciated.

Comment: What is the distance between REST requests and your web-services? Another word, the latency is caused by network or simply the rest requests just slow. Had you consider cache warm-up for REST requests?

Comment: @ajreal, What is cache warm-up?

Comment: The warm up is to pre-load a set of data so that the memcache gets populated with valid data from REST. Meaning, instead of letting your application to determine which REST URL, you can run a background job to pre-fetch these REST URL. You can use a database or file to keep track on REST URL you had executed in your application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was some pretty quick turnaround, but I went back through and profiled my app by echoing out `microtime()` throughout the relevant processes. Turns out that I'm not parallelizing my cURL requests and that's where I take the real hit. It takes approximately 2 seconds to do that, which means very long delays while each cURL request is done in succession.

Comment: in such case, consider to use curl_multi_exec - http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-exec.php

Comment: @ajreal Thanks for the advice on that. That is indeed what I ended up using.